# what is type look like /cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ in ruby

Tags: ruby, types

i see
`/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/` in ruby but I don't have information about this data what is it ?
for example

```
irb(main):001:0> /trwaw/
=> /trwaw/
```

Comment: it looks like a regular expression https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/06/ruby-regex/ where you're searching through some text for some other matching text

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about the class of an object then ask:

```
3.1.0 :001 > /trwaw/.class
 => Regexp
```

As @Jad says, it's a Regular Expression.